# Adding an attribute to xml document child node using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create an element and defining the path to the xml document, one of my tries was:

```
XElement main = XElement.Load(xmlpath);
```

Then i tried to select the existing element that I want to add an attribute

```
main.XPathSelectElement("/Row/ip_addresses").SetAttributeValue("id", sp_range.ToString());
```

Las tried these both

```
main.XPathSelectElement("/Row/ip_addresses").ReplaceAttributes("id", sp_range.ToString());
```

There is no errors presented in this code just nothing happens to the xml document and the existing Element, the existing child element is and the Parent is I am using Xpath to navigate to the child element that I want to add attribute to that don't exist according to Linq we are supposed to be able to change attributes that exist or don't exist and change ElementTags that exist or create Elements that don't exist.

Please any advise would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be persisting/saving the changes...

Try the [`XElement.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.save.aspx) method

Comment: Its saying it needs to be serialized to a writer before being able use the main.save; it red lining.

Comment: You can just test the value if its getting updated by calling main.ToString(); The reason its not updating anything is because you have incorrect node path.

Comment: Thank you sir it worked I just need to point to the xml file path and it saved it.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting from "Row" which doesn't exist under the current element. Current element itself is the "Row". As such, you need to select from the root `"/ip_addresses"`, not from `"/Row/ip_addresses"`.

```
main.XPathSelectElement("/ip_addresses").SetAttributeValue("id",sp_range.ToString()));
```

Comment: the root element is Import the parent is Row and the child I am trying to access in the XML is ip_addresses  so my xpath is either Row/ip_addresses which Selects all elements that are children of Row. or //ip_addresses which gets all ip_addresses no matter where they are in the XML but neither is working